# How to create JSONArray using string in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How to create `JSONArray` using string in `flutter` like this :

```
String abc= "[{ "msg": "msg 1",  "asc": "asc 1" },......{ "message1": "msg 2", "asc": "asc 2"  }]";
```

Comment: Use `'` or `"""` as the Dart string delimiters to avoid conflicting with the JSON string `"` delimiters. So, fx: `String abc = '{"msg":"msg1"}';`

Answer (score 1):

```
String source = //json string array

List<T> fromJson(String source) => fromMap(json.decode(source));

static List<T> fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
  return map((m) => T( 
   msg:m['msg']
   asc:m['asc']));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try following

```
class Data {
  final String msg;
  final String asc;

  const Data(this. msg, this. asc);
}


List<Data> parseData(String abc) {
  final parsed = json.decode(abc).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

  return parsed.map<Data>((json) => Data.fromJson(json)).toList();
}
```

It will return list of your jsonArray from String.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a small part of parsing than it's okay to manual parsing as per given above solution.
I would recommend you use some tool to generate it for you.

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12737-json-to-dart-class-jsontodartclass-

This IntelliJ plugin where you just paste your JSON and it will generate all the boilerplate code for you.

If you are not an IntelliJ user. You can use this website
https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/

For advance try https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json

Answer (score -1):

Best approach will be, Create a model.

```
class MyDataModel{
  String msg;
  String asc;

  MyDataModel({this.msg, this.asc});

  MyDataModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    msg = json['msg'];
    asc = json['asc'];
  }
}
```

Then import,

```
import 'dart:convert';
```

And finally you can make it,

```
String abc =
      '[{ "msg": "msg 1", "asc": "asc 1" },{ "msg": "msg 2", "asc": "asc 2" }]';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<MyDataModel> dataList = parseJson(abc);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Text(dataList[1].msg),
    );
  }

  List<MyDataModel> parseJson(String str) {
    return List<MyDataModel>.from(
        json.decode(str).map((x) => MyDataModel.fromJson(x)));
  }
```